# Whats the most elegant way to add two numbers that are Optional<BigDecimal>

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

I need to perform an add operation on two big decimals that are wrapped optionals:

```
Optional<BigDecimal> ordersTotal;
Optional<BigDecimal> newOrder;
```

I want to achieve ordersTotal += newOrder 
It's important to note that if both values are empty the result should likewise be empty (ie not zero).

Here is what I came up with:

```
ordersTotal = ordersTotal.flatMap( b -> Optional.of(b.add(newOrder.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO))));
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: If they're both empty, should the result be 0 or empty?

Comment: If they're both empty result should also be empty - will update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if you'll consider it more elegant, but here's one alternative:

```
ordersTotal = Optional.of(ordersTotal.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO).add(newOrder.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)));
```

Another, based on [@user140547's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498661/1553851):

```
ordersTotal = Stream.of(ordersTotal, newOrder)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add);
```

Note that the first version returns `Optional.of(BigDecimal.ZERO)` even when both optionals are empty, whereas the second will return `Optional.empty()` in such a case.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use the second code snippet - it is the most concise and most general since it can add any number of optionals

Comment: In Java 9, you can use `Stream.of(ordersTotal, newOrder) .flatMap(Optional::stream) .reduce(BigDecimal::add);`…

Answer (score 16):

I think the suggested answers of using streams or chains of methods on optionals are very clever, but perhaps so clever as to be obscure. The OP has modeled this as `ordersTotal += newOrder` with the exception that if both are empty, the result should be empty instead of zero. Maybe it would be reasonable to write the code so that it says that:

```
if (!ordersTotal.isPresent() && !newOrder.isPresent()) {
    result = Optional.empty();
} else {
    result = Optional.of(ordersTotal.orElse(ZERO).add(newOrder.orElse(ZERO)));
}
```

While this isn't the shortest, it clearly expresses exactly what the OP asked for.

Now I've assigned the computed value to `result` but the OP actually wanted to assign it back to `ordersTotal`. If we know both are empty, we can then skip the then-clause that assigns empty to `ordersTotal`. Doing that, and then inverting the condition gives something simpler:

```
if (ordersTotal.isPresent() || newOrder.isPresent()) {
    ordersTotal = Optional.of(ordersTotal.orElse(ZERO).add(newOrder.orElse(ZERO)));
}
```

Now, this tends to obscure the both-empty special case, which might not be a good idea. On the other hand, this says "add the values if either is non-empty" which might make a lot of sense for the application.

Comment: Everyone who is too lazy too read this very good answer can also watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&feature=youtu.be&t=1800

Comment: @LazerBass Thanks for pointing to my talk! For other readers, this is a talk I gave at Devoxx 2016 entitled "Optional: The Mother of all Bikesheds".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stream of optionals. Then you can make a stream of bigdecimals, and then reduce those bigdecimals, or else return 0.

This has the advantage that you don't have to change the code if you want to do that more than two optionals.

(code can be added later if needed, currently I don't have access to a computer)

Comment: i don't want to return zero though. I want an empty optional (unless one of big decimals is actually zero). Your solution seems even more verbose however

Comment: @maxTrialfire: Well see shmosel's solution. Java 9 will have an Optional.stream() method which can reduce its verbosity. Anyway, in my opinion elegance also means generality, so you don't have to rewrite everything when using 3 or 5 Optionals.

Comment: True. Furthermore I realise that "code elegance" can be subjective

Answer (score 1):

Note that your solution

```
ordersTotal=ordersTotal.flatMap(b -> Optional.of(b.add(newOrder.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO))));
```

will produce an empty `Optional`, if `ordersTotal` is empty, even if `newOrder` is not.

This could be fixed by changing it to

```
ordersTotal=ordersTotal
    .map(b -> Optional.of(b.add(newOrder.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO))))
    .orElse(newOrder);
```

but I’d prefer

```
ordersTotal=ordersTotal
    .map(b -> newOrder.map(b::add).orElse(b))
    .map(Optional::of).orElse(newOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but how about this?

```
orderTotal = !newOrder.isPresent()? 
             orderTotal : 
             newOrder.flatMap(v -> Optional.of(v.add(orderTotal.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO));
```

My thinking behind this approach is like this:

- Behind all the shinny Optional etc. the basic logic here is still
  orderTotal += newOrder
- Before the first newOrder exists orderTotal does not exist, which is represented by an empty Optional in the code.
- If a newOrder does not exist yet (another empty Optional), no operation is necessary at all, i.e. there is no need to modify orderTotal
- If there is a newOrder, invoke its flatMap(..) as presented in maxTrialfire's original post.

Answer (score 0):

Optional and Stream here do not fit together elegantly.

The best in java 8 is:

```
ordersTotaI = !ordersTotaI.isPresent() ? newOrder
         : !newOrder.isPresent() ? ordersTotaI
         : Optional.of(ordersTotaI.get().add(newOrder.get()));
```

However the good news is, that java 9 will add some nice (and also ugly) functionality to Optional.

Comment: I think using isPresent() defeats the purpose of using Optionals. I may as well get rid of the Optional wrapper and use the inner BigDecimal and do a if (value == null) or ternary operator as in your code `value == null ? :`

Comment: @maxTrialfire java 9 adds `.stream()` if I remember correctly. Maybe that helps. However already one easily can get a Stream of BigDecimal. An empty stream should yield an Optonal.empty, a non-empty  stream adding to ZERO. And that I do not see. You are right on those points.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is your requirement not your solution. An empty Optional is not zero but a missing value. You're basically asking that 5 + NaN is equal to 5. Optional's flatMap guides you to the happy path: 5 + Nan is Nan and this is exactly what flatMap does.

Comment: Stuart Marks presented this at Java One today as one of the few cases where it might be legitimate to use `isPresent`. But I am inclined to agree with Mario--the requirement is very strange. If a missing single missing argument is interpreted as zero, then having both arguments missing should also yield a zero. That's easily achieved with two calls to `orElse`. But the much more interesting question is "what if both arguments must be present?" Then the answer is `first.flatMap(f -> second.map(s -> f.add(s)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to reassign to `ordersTotal`, you'll notice that `ordersTotal` only changes if `newOrder` is present.

You can thus start with that check, and write it as:

```
if (newOrder.isPresent()) {
    ordersTotal = newOrder.map(ordersTotal.orElse(ZERO)::add);
}
```

<sub>(This could be considered as a simplification of [Stuart Marks' second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539532/525036). This is also a case where the method reference cannot be converted back to a lambda, due to `ordersTotal` not being effectively final)</sub>

If you start by this check, there is also another possible “*clever*” approach:

```
if (newOrder.isPresent()) {
    ordersTotal = ordersTotal.map(o -> newOrder.map(o::add)).orElse(newOrder);
}
```

where the intermediate `map()` returns an `Optional<Optional<BigDecimal>>` whose inner `Optional` cannot be empty. I wouldn't consider it a good solution due to its bad readability, and I would thus recommend the first option or one of Stuart's solutions.