# How to join two Optional<String> with a delimiter in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have two `Optional` strings, `name1` and `name2`. I want to join the two such that the result is also an Optional with:

1. If either one is non-empty, the result should be the non-empty name.
2. If both are non-empty, I want the result to be joined with the delimiter `AND`.
3. If both are empty, the result should be an empty `Optional`

My attempt at this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
name1.ifPresent(sb::append);
name2.ifPresent(s -> {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(" AND ");
    }
    sb.append(s);
}
Optional<String> joinedOpt = Optional.ofNullable(Strings.emptyToNull(sb.toString()));
```

This works, but seems ugly and not very functional.

PS: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46473336/1314028) but the accepted answer is wrong. Specifically, if `name1` is empty and `name2` is not, it returns an empty optional.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539532/3474

Comment: Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to stream and `reduce()`:

```
Optional<String> joinedOpt = Stream.of(name1, name2)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .reduce((a, b) -> a + " AND " + b);
```

Feel free to replace the filter/map combo with Java 9 or Guava as others have suggested.

Comment: Took me some good time to understand this solution, so it's excellent in the sense that it does the job but in my opinion, it's a bit time consuming to understand so readability is quite low. when I say readability I mean in the sense that "another" person could look at the code and say "ah this is what it does". but that maybe just me...

Comment: @Aominè. I think it is just a personal opinion. To me it looks like a clean and readable solution. Maybe it is because of past MapReduce work. My only comment is about creating too many intermediate `StringBuilder` objects on each element instead of potentially reusing single one when using `Collectors.joining`.

Comment: @tsolakp yup, it's an opinion based comment as stated. btw I like the answer ;-) . Anyway as for _My only comment is about creating too many intermediate StringBuilder objects on each element instead of potentially reusing single one when using Collectors.joining._ , remember that we will have at most 2 (plus the " AND ") string objects so it's probably not worthwhile using a `StringBuilder` anyway.

Comment: Concatenation always uses StringBuilder under the hood. But the reduction only gets called once, at most.

Comment: @shmosel not always, starting from 9

Answer (score 7):

Possible solution in Java 1.9 would be

```
 Optional<String> name1 = Optional.of("x");
 Optional<String> name2 = Optional.of("y");
 String s = Stream.concat(name1.stream(), name2.stream()).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
 System.out.println(s);
```

With Java 1.8 there is no way that you can go from an Optional to a Stream. However, you can add such a conversion quite easily to Java 1.8.

```
static <T> Stream<T> of(Optional<T> option) {
    return option.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```

And now you can use the `of` method to concatenate both streams.

Now, to get an empty `Optional` if there is no result, you can wrap the result into an Optional and do a simple filter.

```
Optional<String> result = Optional.of(collect).filter(Optional::isPresent);
```

Comment: Nice! I guess one could use Guava's [Streams.stream](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Optional-) to do the same in Java 8

Comment: @spinlok Yes, if Guava is available then you sorted.

Comment: This doesn't return an empty optional when they're both empty.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi also why is there a `orElseGet` instead of `orElse(Stream.empty())`, its not like creating an empty stream is expensive

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different flavor using `Collectors.joining`:

```
    Optional<String> result  = Optional.of( 
        Stream.of(so1, so2)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect( Collectors.joining(" AND ") ) 
    ).filter( s -> !s.isEmpty() );
```

What I like about `Collectors.joining` is that Java streams can potentially reuse single StringBuilder class instead of creating a new one when doing `+` operation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, trying to get functional with `Optional` (or `Stream`) just obscures what you are trying to express in your code.

To me, the main idea here is that if both values are present, they should be concatenated with " AND ". Here is an attempt to focus on that:

```
Optional<String> joinedOpt;
if (name1.isPresent() && name2.isPresent()) {
    joinedOpt = Optional.of(name1.get() + " AND " + name2.get());
} else {
    joinedOpt = name1.isPresent() ? name1 : name2;
}
```

I might be misinterpreting his message, but this approach was inspired by [Stuart Marks' answer to a similiar question,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539532/3474) which he discussed in more depth in [his Devoxx talk](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=30m) about the choices he made as he helped design `Optional`.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Not very fancy, maybe, but 100% expressive, the intention is so clear and the code is very readable.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner especially if there would be proper deconstruction patterns implemented (like switch statements in 10), something like `name1 isPresentGet String x` (totally made up syntax here)

Answer (score 1):

Close to the accepted answer

```
Optional<String> joinedOpt = Stream.of(name1, name2)
            .flatMap(x -> x.map(Stream::of).orElse(null))
            .reduce((a, b) -> a + " AND " + b);
```

Or in java-9:

```
Optional<String> joinedOpt = Stream.of(name1, name2)
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .reduce((a, b) -> a + " AND " + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a streaming solution, which filters for those `Optional`s that are present, then extracts the elements and uses a built-in Collector to join the remaining elements.  Then it tests if the result is empty at the end to return an empty `Optional`.

It accepts a `List` of `Optional`s so it covers a more general case than just two elements.

```
public Optional<String> optionalJoin(List<Optional<String>> strings) {
    String result = strings.stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
    return result.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner without Streams, but not especially elegant:

```
    public static Optional<String> concat(Optional<String> name1, Optional<String> name2) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(name1.map(s1 -> name2.map(s2 -> s1 + " AND " + s2).orElse(s1)).orElse(name2.orElse(null)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(concat(Optional.of("A"), Optional.of("B")));
        System.out.println(concat(Optional.of("A"), Optional.empty()));
        System.out.println(concat(Optional.empty(), Optional.of("B")));
        System.out.println(concat(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
    }
```